# What was the role of Scotland during the Hundred Years War?

Tags: middle-ages, england, france, scotland, hundred-years-war

Scotland was the enemy of England, as they had regained their [independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_War_of_Scottish_Independence). It made sense for them to join hands with the French forces. And I heard something like that in an [Extra Credits](https://www.youtube.com/extracredits/videos) video. But can you elaborate how exactly they helped ??

Comment: Have you looked at [Hundred Years' War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hundred_Years%27_War#Franco-Scot_alliance)? Also, see this HSE question: [How many Scots were present at the Battle of Bauge?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/66233/how-many-scots-were-present-at-the-battle-of-bauge). If these links don't help, please edit your question to clarify what you are looking for.

Comment: [Please document preliminary research](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/1401)

Comment: @LarsBosteen Thanks brother

Comment: battle of herrings?

Answer (score 4):

**Auld Alliance**

It all dates back to a treaty signed between Scotland and France in 1295, named the Auld Alliance, when both nations agreed to help eachother should either country be attacked by England.

[The Scotsman](https://www.scotsman.com/arts-and-culture/scottish-fact-day-auld-alliance-1515918)

> However, the alliance was never officially cemented until John Balliol and Philip IV of France signed a treaty in 1295.

> The pact bound the Auld Alliance to help each other should either country be attacked by England.

**Scots in the French army**

The Kingdom of Scotland kept their end of the bargain and their forces served in the French military during the Wars of the Roses.

[War History Online](https://www.warhistoryonline.com/instant-articles/elite-scottish-warriors-helped.html?chrome=1)

> Scottish forces served in the French military throughout most of the Hundred Years’ War, earning a reputation as capable fighters in the process.

**Battle of Bauge**

I already asked a question myself regarding this subject, which can be found [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/66233/how-many-scots-were-present-at-the-battle-of-bauge) and I received a rather brilliant answer informing me that the Scots at the [Battle of Bauge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Baug%C3%A9) outnumbered the French by approximately four or five to one, which should give one an idea of just how much the Scots contributed towards French victory.

**Other battles**

Other battles during the Wars of the Roses which involved the Kingdom of Scotland to one degree or other, include:

- [Battle of Cravant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Cravant) - English victory
- [Battle of Verneuil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Verneuil) - English victory
- [Siege of Orleans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Orl%C3%A9ans) - Franco-Scots victory
- [Battle of Herrings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Herrings) - English victory
- [Battle of Wakefield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Wakefield) - Welsh victory, supported by Franco-Scots
- [Battle of Bosworth Field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Bosworth_Field) - Welsh victory, supported by Franco-Scots

The above information is taken from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_battles_involving_the_Kingdom_of_Scotland) wikipedia article, named, "List of battles involving the Kingdom of Scotland".

**What was the role of Scotland during the Hundred years war?**

Scotland were French military allies due to their treaty of alliance and they fought for France against England alongside French troops during the Wars of the Roses as part of their agreement.

Comment: An interesting take: "Franco-Scots victory".  Whilst there were Scots (and possibly Frenchmen too) at both the battles of Wakefield and Bosworth, they were there in a supporting role to the main belligerents: the Houses of York and Lancaster.  You might better describe the latter as a Welsh victory, since the Lancastrians having run out of candidates had to scout around for a new leader, Henry Tudor.

Comment: @Martin Ok, I have edited it to do Wales justice

Comment: @Martin So Tudor was Welsh and the Lancastrians supported him?

Comment: Harri Tudur was descended on his father's side from Tuduriaid Penmynydd (the Tudors of Penmynydd) in Anglesey. His mother was Lady Margaret Beaufort whose father was the offspring of the Duke of Lancaster and his mistress, Kathrine Synford.  Basically the Lancastrians had run out of strong claimants for the throne and Beaufort, who was a shrewd political operator, maneuvered her son as the pretender.  Beaufort is one of the suspects over the Princes in the Tower; by eliminating them and casting blame towards Richard she paved the way for Henry's succession.